# How can I always bring the application to front when opening a new file?

Tags: gnome3, open-files, launcher

Running in a GNOME 3.28.0/Wayland desktop. If I right-click on a text file and select "Open with other application", the application I choose is brought to the front when it launches. However, if I repeat the process (the application is already running), the new text file is opened in a new tab, but the application remains in the back.

This happens for both Text Editor and Geany.

How can I ensure that when I open a file, the application it is opened in is always brought to the front?

Comment: People say it's "ghost" bug https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=348339 though I think it has to do with something else... I have 3.22.1 on one machine and it works fine and I have 3.28.0 on another and it behaves as you describe above...

Comment: All right, I figured it out. It's related to `wayland`. If you chose `gnome on Xorg` at the `GDM` login screen it all works fine. If you chose the default `gnome` (the default means `gnome on Wayland`) then the apps no longer get focus when you open new documents and remain instead in the background. Further search reveals it's a [known bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=766284)